# Is there a way to increase the maximum allow url length for incoming requests on Apache HTTPd?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, httpd, httpd.conf

I'm running a web services site on Apache HTTPd and every once in while I get an error indicating the incoming URL is too long (HTTPError: HTTP Error 414: Request-URI Too Large).

My site is servicing programs rather than browser so I'm not worried about the 2K browser limit.

Is there any way to get increase the acceptable URI length?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Increasing [LimitRequestLine](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestline) parameter might help. But still I wonder what kind of URI's you have, since under normal operation I have never needed to touch that value ...